# Why is UpdatePanel working on local IIS but not on remote IIS?

Tags: asp.net

It seems that most of AJAX is working fine for my web site(VB.Net), but `UpdatePanel` on remote **IIS6** doesnt work at all.

I've checked setting in the web.config file. it's true.

Comment: Did you install ajaxtoolkit on remote server?

Comment: yes...Ajax is installed.

Comment: wild guesses: library not present on your server, path of some js scripts different.
if you need more specific help, put a more specific problem. like error messages etc.

Comment: Check if you have System.Web.Extensions.Design.dll, System.Web.Extensions.dll, AjaxControlToolkit on server, if they are present on local

Comment: yes...there are all dlls.

Comment: You have to check if you get an error in javascript? Do you get postback instead of ajax call?

Comment: I mean, when I use update panel in one of my page, in locall its working fine but in remote IIS page is refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all the suggestions but still my update panels on .net 3.5 would not work on my production server but worked fine on my development machine. I checked the Web.config files for consistency and everything was the same except for:

```
compilation debug="false"
```

On my production server and:

```
compilation debug="true"
```

On my development server.

So as a last resort, I changed my production server to "true" and everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this URL:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/Don_1920_t-run-production-ASP.NET-Applications-with-debug_3D001D20_true_1D20_-enabled

There is a section on "What about binaries compiled with debug symbols?" which I think will help you with your issue. You should change you debug flag back to false on production.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still working with a legacy website, check if the web.config has the xhtmlConformance node set to "Legacy".  Commenting this out resolved the issue with the UpdatePanel not working. Apparently this was added automatically when using the VS 2003 to 2005 migration tool. As far back as 2006, Scott Gu said not to use it.

https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/gotcha-don-t-use-xhtmlconformance-mode-legacy-with-asp-net-ajax

```
<!--<xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy" />-->
```